# Remove single character values and all consonant values from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that changes constantly, depending on the user input. It takes the user input word, and then splits it into `array_unique` where it has all possible combinations of letters. I then use a `usort` function to sort the array from smallest to largest in alphabetical order.

I need to be able to remove from the array any values that are 1 character, and any that are all consonants like "lp", "lpp", "pp", "ds".

```
array('d','e','p','r','s','y','de','dp','dr','ds','dy','ep','er','es','ey','pr','ps',
      'py','rs','ry','sy','dep','der','des','dey','dpr','dps','dpy','drs','dry','dsy',
      'epr','eps','epy','ers','ery','esy','prs','pry','psy','rsy','depr','deps','depy',
      'ders','dery','desy','dprs','dpry','dpsy','drsy','eprs','epry','epsy','ersy','prsy',
      'deprs','depry','depsy','dersy','dprsy','eprsy','deprsy');
```

Above is an example of an array i would have if the user put in "spyder". I need to be able to remove the single character results at the beginning, and I need to be able to remove any values made entirely of all consonants. For the sake of this application, I am not considering "Y" a consonant, and will group it with the other vowels A,E,I,O,U.

So ideally, my array would look like this:

```
array('de','dy','ep','er','es','ey','py','ry','sy','dep','der','des','dey','dpy','dry',
      'dsy','epr','eps','epy','ers','ery','esy','pry','psy','rsy','depr','deps','depy',
      'ders','dery','desy','dpry','dpsy','drsy','eprs','epry','epsy','ersy','prsy',
      'deprs','depry','depsy','dersy','dprsy','eprsy','deprsy');
```

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried?  It looks like you just want someone else to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` with two conditions on each item. First, check that the length of the item is not 1 using `strlen`, then `trim` all consonants from the item and see if there's anything left.

```
$result = array_filter($your_array, function($x) {
    return strlen($x) != 1 && trim($x, 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz');
});
```

Comment: Not sure if i am implementing this correctly as i am having issues: <?
    $anagram = array("red","blue","a","ppp");

    $result = array_filter($anagram, function($x) {
    return strlen($x) != 1 && trim($x, 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz');
    });
    print_r($result);
    ?>

Comment: That looks right. `$result` should be `['red','blue']`.